# Applescript to open youtube in safari private mode

Tags: applescript

How can the youtube be opened in safari private mode?

I have tried this, but it is not working:

```
tell application "Safari" to activate
tell application "System Events"
tell process "Safari"
      click menu item "New Private Window" of menu "File" of menu bar 1
      open location "https://www.youtube.com"  -- this will open default browser
end tell
end tell
```

My default browser is Chrome, and it opens youtube in chrome not in safari private mode.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* works for me:

For **Safari** use:

```
activate application "Safari"

tell application "System Events" to ¬
    click menu item "New Private Window" of ¬
        menu "File" of menu bar 1 of ¬
        application process "Safari"

tell application "Safari" to ¬
    set URL of current tab of ¬
        front window to "https://www.youtube.com"
```

<sub>Note: If one prefers, each of the two `tell` *statements* can be all on a line of its own by removing the `¬` *line continuation* character and the invisible *linefeed* character that follows.</sub>

For **Google Chrome** use:

```
activate application "Google Chrome"

tell application "System Events" to ¬
    click menu item "New Incognito Window" of ¬
        menu "File" of menu bar 1 of ¬
        application process "Google Chrome"

tell application "Google Chrome" to ¬
    set URL of active tab of ¬
        front window to "https://www.youtube.com"
```

<sub>Note: If one prefers, each of the two `tell` *statements* can be all on a line of its own by removing the `¬` *line continuation* character and the invisible *linefeed* character that follows.</sub>

---

Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any error handling as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any error handling as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1).

Answer (score 3):

I don't really have a better solution for Safari than the one offered by @user3439894. The only thing I would have done differently would be to make the new private window using this code (which is probably "6 of 1 or 1/2 a dozen of the other")

```
tell application "Safari" to activate
tell application "System Events" to tell its application process "Safari"
    set frontmost to true
    keystroke "n" using {shift down, command down}
end tell
```

However, you may prefer this solution for Google Chrome because it does not require the use of System Events and it does not require Google Chrome to be active or frontmost.

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    set incognitoWindow to (make new window with properties {mode:"incognito"})
    repeat while loading of active tab of incognitoWindow
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
    set URL of active tab of incognitoWindow to "http://youtube.com"
end tell
```

Comment: RE: Safari code: 1. As currently written, it does not preform the requested task as the URL has not been set! 2. If you are going to use `keystroke` you do not need to use `... to tell its application process "Safari"` as System Events is the one doing it. When using the aforementioned, `set frontmost to true` is just redundant as you already activated Safari, which sets it frontmost! RE: Google Chrome code: While it doesn't require the use of System Events and it does not require Google Chrome to be active or frontmost nonetheless, it brings Google Chrome frontmost, so that's a wash. Cont'd..

Comment: Cont'd... Additionally you do not need the `repeat` _loop_, nor do you need to wait for the window to finish loading in this case, and the following two lines of inside of the `tell application "Google Chrome"` _block_ does it: `make new window with properties {mode:"incognito"}` and `set URL of active tab of front window to "http://youtube.com"` Because `make new window...` makes Google Chrome front most and the new wind frontmost two. No need for such rigamarole as you've coded.

Comment: OMG, this! I've been looking for this for years. `make new window with properties {mode:"incognito"}`

And combining it with a script to open Chrome if it's not running means I can easily open an Incognito window any time.

Answer (score 2):

```
tell application "Opera"
    try
        make new window with properties {mode:"incognito"}
    end try
        set URL of active tab of front window to "https://yoururl.com"
end tell
```

I wrapped `make new window with properties {mode:"incognito"}` in `try` because I get an error `"Opera got an error: AppleEvent handler failed." number -10000` because i use Opera browser.

It is not necessary when using Google Chrome.